# Can't get PHP array values to reset properly in loop

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

Goal is to populate an array in a loop with values so they can be called later based on a key rather than having loops within loops. The array actually contains many keys and they all seem to work except this one.

The problem is that either the value resets on the first iteration and then doesn't increase, or that the value is added regardless of variable matching.

```
[$shig query]
$check = array();
$x = 0;
$previd = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($shig)) {
    $sid = $row['sid'];
    $num = $row['num'];

    if ($num == 0) { $x++; }
    $check[$sid] = array('x' => $x);

    //This resets $x if $sid is new
    if ($sid != $previd) { 
        //$x = 0;
    }
    $previd = $sid;
}

print_r($check['3118']); //this should be x = 4

print_r($check['3255']); //this should be x = 2
```

`$num` is always an integer 0 or greater.

---

What happens... with the **current loop.**..

`$check['3118'][x]` = 4 -- this is correct 
`$check['3255'][x]` = 6 -- this is **incorrect** (sum total of x value)

---

If I **uncomment the `$x = 0;`** variable reset....

`$check['3118'][x]` = 1 -- this is **incorrect** (only sees first iteration of loop)
`$check['3255'][x]` = 2 -- this is correct

---

I can't seem to work out the logic to get both print_r() functions to output proper values.

**How can I reset the `$x` variable when the primary array key changes so that each primary key contains the proper value for `x`?**

<sub>(Personal localhost app so mysql updating isn't imperative, but I know I should.)</sub>

Comment: It looks like your goal is to count the number of zero `num` values for each `sid`. Is that right?

Comment: yes, I want x to equal the total number of rows where num = 0 for *that* id

Comment: Could you provide an example array of several `'sid'-'num'` tuples to reproduce.

Comment: btw, mysql_* are quite deprecated

Comment: I realize sql is pretty much dead @AlexBlex :) and not the last line of my question :) This is a personal localhost app.. nothing for the public so.. until I upgrade php/sql on my localhost.. not an issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the posted PHP in the question. The issue was the query needs to be sorted properly.

**Adding `ORDER BY sid ASC` to the query itself solves the issue.**

This was discovered by running `print_r()` on the query and seeing it was out of sequential order. Once that was corrected the PHP in the question works fine (provided that `$x=0` is uncommented).

Answer (score 1):

I would do it a bit differently. I may be missing something, though. The code in your question looks like it might matter if the `sid`s are consecutive and this doesn't handle that, but it will get the count of `0` values for each `sid`.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($shig)) {

   $sid = $row['sid'];
   if (!isset($check[$sid])) { $check[$sid]['x'] = 0; }
   if ($row['num'] == 0) { $check[$sid]['x']++; }
}
```

Also, unless you're getting something else from your query at the same time, it would probably be better to just modify the query to do this in the database instead, like:

```
SELECT sid, COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE num = 0 GROUP BY sid;
```

Comment: Okay.. send look... bad bit of random code I forgot to comment out. this appears to be going in the right direction....thanks!

Comment: Okay this works provided each `sid` *has* an num value. However if the `sid` has no `num` count (no rows where num=0), the x value is merely continued through the loop until a new `num` value is encountered.

Comment: I think that should do it. Sorry if the indentation is a bit off. I'm on my phone now and writing code on it is kind of awkward.

Comment: That's really what I already had :) Just increasing array values directly rather than a variable then throwing the variable into the array :) Solved the repetition - it was due to an uncleared variable in the main page loop.  Your solution works, but it really is essentially the same as what I already had. And suffers from the same issue. What actually solved the issue was to add **ORDER BY sid ASC** to the query itself to sort the rows properly. Discovered when I ran print_r() on the query. hate it when it's those small things.

Comment: I'd actually delete the question if not for your answer preventing that :)

Comment: I can delete the answer if you'd like to do that. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "suffers from the same issue," though. This code doesn't depend on the results being in any particular order.